# TensorFlow upgrade to 1.0.1

Tags: tensorflow

I upgraded my server from 1.0.0 :

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

But I get the following discrepancy:

```
(tensorflow)$ pip list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow (1.0.0)
(tensorflow)$ python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
1.0.1
```

Comment: What do you get if you type `pip show tensorflow`?

Comment: Hi @mrry . I get the following output: ---
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstal Tensorflow 1.0.0 (I am using virtualenv), so in order to install just remove the folder 
   $rm -rf
2. Install Tensorflow 1.0.1